# Question regarding a change of variable formula in multivariate integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $L > 1$ and consider a cube $B_{L} = [0,L]^{3} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$. I want to simplify the expression:
$$\int \int_{B_{L}\times B_{L}}f(x-y)dxdy$$
assuming the integral exists.

My approach is the following. Let $u = x-y$ and $v = x+y$, so that $x= \frac{1}{2}(u+v)$ an $y = \frac{1}{2}(u-v)$. The Jacobian matrix of this transformation is:
$$Jf(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 
I & 0 \\
0 & - I
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $I$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. Hence, $|Jf(x,y)| = \frac{1}{2}$ and:
$$\int \int_{B_{L}\times B_{L}}f(x-y)dxdy = \frac{1}{2}\int\int f(u)dudv = \int_{B_{L}} f(u)du$$
where I used that, because $x,y \in B_{L}$ then $v \in B_{2L}$. I am not quite sure of this last step. Is it correct and is my formula correct?

Comment: First, your determinant is way off. Second, the region of integration becomes much more complicated. Draw the picture in $\Bbb R^2$ when the original interval lives just in $ \Bbb R^1$.